# JSON parsing in javascript for json-ld

Tags: javascript, json, json-ld

Trying to parse a JSON from [json-ld](http://json-ld.org/)

Here is the JSON below:

```
{
  "@context": "http://json-ld.org/contexts/person.jsonld",
  "@id": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/John_Lennon",
  "name": "John Lennon",
  "born": "1940-10-09",
  "spouse": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Cynthia_Lennon"
}
```

So I am trying to do this:

```
var jsonData= {
  "@context": "http://json-ld.org/contexts/person.jsonld",
  "@id": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/John_Lennon",
  "name": "John Lennon",
  "born": "1940-10-09",
  "spouse": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Cynthia_Lennon"
};

console.log(jsonData.@context);// Error:Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
console.log(jsonData.name);// John Lenon
```

How do i parse the @context then? Please suggest.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
console.log(jsonData['@context']);
```

More about Javascript [Property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors): dot notation and bracket notation.

Answer (score 3):

Please use

`console.log(jsonData['@id']).`

Not only this also you cannot use a Javascript variable name starting with @.

you can refer to this for javascript variable naming convention. https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers

Comment: This is a jsonld data structe. It needs a `@context` to be defined, as well as several other tokens defined in json-ld.

Comment: If you are interested in it you can read it in the [_Syntax Tokens and Keywords_](https://json-ld.org/spec/latest/json-ld/#syntax-tokens-and-keywords) specification.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse it as:

```
var jsonData = {
    "@context": "http://json-ld.org/contexts/person.jsonld",
    "@id": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/John_Lennon",
    "name": "John Lennon",
    "born": "1940-10-09",
    "spouse": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Cynthia_Lennon"
};

console.log(jsonData['@context']);`
```